# I suspect memory fault. How do I identify it?

Tags: memory, crash

I recently replaced the RAM in my computer with 4 modules of 8GB each. Since then I'm experiencing random crashes of foreground and background programs, sporadic input lag and full, unrecoverable freezes. I ran memtest86 and nothing came up.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and the logs don't show anything when the system crashes. How can I diagnose this problem and possibly identify which memory is the faulty one?

My motherboard for [reference](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/GA-B85M-DS3H-rev-30#ov).

Comment: You need at least 3-5 successful tests passes with  `memtest86`. Try also `memtest86+`. Check motherboard for the presence of bulged capacitors

Comment: If the errors are frequent enough, you might be able to use the computer with just one stick in at a time and see if it crashes only on one of them

Comment: There are many possible causes, including bad/low quality power supply. If your system can run without crashing with two of the new sticks at a time and you've eliminated bad memory slots, your most likely culprit is the PSU. Using more than two sticks can easily put a bad PSU to its knees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually people use dedicated "memory testing" software. There is some software that can diagnose most or all of your memory while the operating system runs, but sometimes the software is blocked (by the operating system) from accessing some of the memory.

Usually people just boot the computer to some software that runs instead of the operating system (sacrificing multitasking, so experiencing some downtime of normal operations) to simplify the tester software's ability to access the entirety of the memory to be tested.

The most popular solutions are probably:
* Memtest86+
* Memtest
* Windows Memory Diagnostics (if you have that conveniently available)

Go to [Memtest86+'s home page at http://memtest.org](http://memtest.org) and download Memtest86+, unless you know that Memtest86+ is built into another CD you have.  (I've seen it on some installation disks for Ubuntu and Linux Mint.)

Usually problems are detected on the first pass, but I've sometimes seen problems detected on a 2nd through 4th pass, and more rarely on a later pass (like a 72nd pass), so you should let this run overnight, if not over a weekend (if you can do that).

Unfortunately, different motherboards/configurations have been known to give RAM different addresses, so once you know there's a problem, the only absolutely certain way to verify which RAM stick is the problem is to try removing them (one or two at a time).  Keep in mind some possibilities: it might not be the RAM stick itself that is causing the issues. It might be the motherboard slot a stick is in or it might be that the RAM just didn't get seated (properly placed) completely right in the motherboard, so removing the RAM and re-inserting might fix things.

If the downtime is impossible, but you can sacrifice some performance/speed, you may want to just try another technique you may want to do is just try halving your RAM, using only two of your sticks.  If that resolves things, you have a good idea that RAM was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I had the impression that the addition of more RAM was using more wattage than the PSU could provide so I removed 2 sticks, dropping to 8gb, and removed my video card and the crashes stopped.